# PLINQO Primary key AND index problem

Tags: indexing, primary-key, codesmith, plinqo

I've two tables, Profile and ProfileCategory

```
ProfileId INT IX
UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PK (For one-to-one mapping with aspnet_membership)
CompanyName
Description

ProfileCategory
CategoryId
ProfileId
```

When I generate the code with PLINGO I get following errors

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.Guid'
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.Guid'

I dived into the generated code and the following..

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("CodeSmith", "5.0.0.0")]
    private void OnProfileList1Remove(Profile entity)
    {
        SendPropertyChanging(null);
        var profileCategory = ProfileCategoryList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryId == CategoryId
            && c.ProfileId == entity.UserId);
        ProfileCategoryList.Remove( profileCategory);
        SendPropertyChanged(null);
    }
```

So the generated code seems to want to compare the index and the primary key

I can manually alter the code but on regeneration it will be altered back.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Here is the profile snipet from the dbml

```
    <Table Name="dbo.Profile" Member="Profile">
        <Type Name="Profile">
          <Column Name="UserId" Storage="_userId" Type="System.Guid" DbType="uniqueidentifier NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />
          <Column Name="ProfileId" Storage="_profileId" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int NOT NULL IDENTITY" CanBeNull="false" />
          <Column Name="CompanyName" Storage="_companyName" Type="System.String" DbType="nvarchar(250) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
          <Column Name="Description" Storage="_description" Type="System.String" DbType="varchar(MAX)" CanBeNull="true" />
          <Column Name="Services" Storage="_services" Type="System.Xml.Linq.XElement" DbType="xml" CanBeNull="true" UpdateCheck="Never" />
          <Column Name="ContactDetails" Storage="_contactDetails" Type="System.Xml.Linq.XElement" DbType="xml" CanBeNull="true" UpdateCheck="Never" />
          <Column Name="Attributes" Storage="_attributes" Type="System.Xml.Linq.XElement" DbType="xml" CanBeNull="true" UpdateCheck="Never" />
          <Column Name="StateId" Storage="_stateId" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
          <Column Name="Views" Storage="_views" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
          <Association Name="User_Profile" Member="User" Storage="_user" ThisKey="UserId" Type="User" IsForeignKey="true" DeleteRule="CASCADE" />
          <Association Name="Profile_ProfileAddress" Member="ProfileAddressList" Storage="_profileAddressList" OtherKey="UserId" Type="ProfileAddress" DeleteOnNull="false" />
          <Association Name="Profile_Review" Member="ReviewList" Storage="_reviewList" ThisKey="ProfileId" OtherKey="ProfileId" Type="Review" DeleteOnNull="false" />
          <Association Name="Profile_ProfileCategory" Member="ProfileCategoryList" Storage="_profileCategoryList" ThisKey="ProfileId" OtherKey="ProfileId" Type="ProfileCategory" />
        </Type>
 </Table>
 <Table Name="dbo.ProfileCategory" Member="ProfileCategory">
    <Type Name="ProfileCategory">
      <Column Name="ProfileCategoryId" Storage="_profileCategoryId" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int NOT NULL IDENTITY" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsDbGenerated="true" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="ProfileId" Storage="_profileId" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="CategoryId" Storage="_categoryId" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Association Name="Category_ProfileCategory" Member="Category" Storage="_category" ThisKey="CategoryId" Type="Category" IsForeignKey="true" />
      <Association Name="Profile_ProfileCategory" Member="Profile" Storage="_profile" ThisKey="ProfileId" OtherKey="ProfileId" Type="Profile" IsForeignKey="true" DeleteRule="CASCADE" />
    </Type>
  </Table>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see that the Foreign Key ProfileCategory.ProfileId  references Profile.ProfileId ?

Comment: Yeah it does. I've checked in the dbml file and I've deleted and recreated the foreign key relationship in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure this wasn't already fixed in a nightly build of [PLINQO](http://community.codesmithtools.com/nightly/PLINQO/plinqo-r1914.zip)? Could you please post the schema (or send to CodeSmith support) for these two tables.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski

Comment: Just did this and and it didnt work. I tried running this over my current project and I also generated a new project at also failed. I have a looked at the Entity.Generated.cst and it appears to be confusing the seperate PK and IX as a many to many relationship.

Comment: I'll add the schema above. Thanks

Comment: Hello,

Where you able to add the schema?

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski